# Puppet Device unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: centos, puppet, openssl, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I installed puppet 4.3 and centos7 to use Puppet Device to manage Cisco routers.
The server hostname is "puppetmaster" (by running `hostnamectl puppetmaster`)
The centos server is running puppet master and agent.

After setting everything up and configuring device.conf when I run sudo puppet device --debug I see these errors:

```
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/devices/r1/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppetmaster]
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/devices/r1/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get local issuer certificate for /CN=puppetmaster]
```

I can run `puppet agent --test` on the server successfully:

```
sudo puppet agent --test
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for puppetmaster
Info: Applying configuration version '1449189804'
```

Here is my /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/device.conf

```
[r1]
type cisco
url telnet://puppet:123456@r1/
```

Here is my /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf

```
[master]
vardir = /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver
logdir = /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver
rundir = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver
pidfile = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.pid
codedir = /etc/puppetlabs/code
dns_alt_names = puppetmaster

[agent]
certname = puppetmaster
server = puppetmaster
```

This has to be some kind of cert problem, like a name mismatch, but I don't know what could be causing it. The agent is running on the same server as the master and I set all the configs correctly (at least I think I did).

Here is the cert returned by puppet:

```
 sudo puppet cert --print --all | grep CN
        Issuer: CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster
        Subject: CN=puppetmaster
```

Here are the raw ca.pem and puppetmaster.pem certs:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem -noout -text | grep CN
        Issuer: CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster
        Subject: CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster
                DirName:/CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster
openssl x509 -in /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/puppetmaster.pem -noout -text | grep CN
        Issuer: CN=Puppet CA: puppetmaster
        Subject: CN=puppetmaster
```

When I run openssl to verify the cert I see the same error:

```
sudo openssl verify -CApath /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/puppetmaster.pem

/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/puppetmaster.pem: CN = puppetmaster
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I confirmed by config settings and went through [the process to clean the certs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html) (mulitple times) but no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK figured it out.

As I said I cleared and regenerated Puppets certs BUT what I didn't do was clear:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/devices/
```

Puppet cached an old cert for the device so it was trying to use that one instead of generating a new one.

After deleting the contents of that folder I was able to run `puppet device`